# Счетчик просмотров php

Tags: php

Сделал счетчик просмотров страницы

`$upd_views = $myrow3['views'] + 1; 
mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE`wall`SET views='$upd_views' WHERE id='$page_id';");`

изначально в бд стоит 0 и когда я просматриваю страницу в просмотрах стает 1 и всё дальше просмотры не защитываются.

Comment: А откуда берется значение в переменной $myrow3['views'] ? И зачем так сложно, может просто `update wall set views=views+1 where id=?`

Comment: @Mike напишыте ваш код в ответе и я его выберу лучшим

Comment: Похоже Вы не инкрементируете $myrow3['views']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение лучше обновлять прямо в базе, так надежнее, чем считать его во вне.

```
update wall set views=views+1 where id=?
```